# Как избежать дубликации кода?

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблон-стратегия

Я новичек, пытаюсь реализовать паттерн стратегия для генерации пароля.
Пароль может быть `simple` , `medium`  и  `strong`.

Из параметров командной строки узнаю какой пароль нужен пользователю и исходя из этого выбирают стратегию.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой что, в функции `use_main_strategy()` сильная дубликация кода.

**Как можно избежать этого?**

main.cpp

```
#include "errors.h"
#include "argparser.h"
#include "alphabet.h"
#include "passwordgenerator.h"
#include "strategy.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

#include <QDebug>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QCommandLineParser>
#include <QScopedPointer>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QFile>

using namespace std;
//использование выбранной стратегии
string use_main_straregy(string _strat, int _lenght_pass, string _alphabet) {

    PasswordGenerator _pwdgen;
    if (_strat == "simple"){
        Simple _strateg;         
        _pwdgen.setStrategy(&_strateg);
       return  _pwdgen.useStrategy(_lenght_pass, _alphabet);
    }
    if (_strat == "medium"){
        Medium _strateg;
        _pwdgen.setStrategy(&_strateg);
       return _pwdgen.useStrategy(_lenght_pass, _alphabet);
    }
    if (_strat == "strong"){
        Strong _strateg;
        _pwdgen.setStrategy(&_strateg);
       return _pwdgen.useStrategy(_lenght_pass, _alphabet);
    }
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    try {
        auto parser = parse_args(QCoreApplication(argc, argv));
        auto strat = select_alphabet(*parser);//выбор стратегии алфавита (слабый,средний или сильный)
        auto length = parser->value("length").toUInt();//длина алфавита

        cout << use_main_straregy(strat,length,alphabet) << endl;


    }
    catch (const exception& ex) {
        cout << "ERROR: " << ex.what() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

strategy.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Strategy {
public:
    virtual ~Strategy() {}
    virtual string use(int lenght,string alpahbet) = 0;
};

class Simple: public Strategy {
public:
    string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmopqrtsuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRTSUVWXYZ0123456789";  
    string use(int lenght,string alpahbet);
};

class Medium: public Strategy {
public:
    string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmopqrtsuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRTSUVWXYZ0123456789!@#_";
    string use(int lenght,string alpahbet);
};

class Strong: public Strategy {
public:
    string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmopqrtsuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRTSUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()-_+=";
    string use(int lenght,string alpahbet);
};
```

Comment: [KISS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF)). Отбросьте лишнююю мишуру (ООП). Чем в **реальности** различаются это 3 случая? Строкой алфавита и длиной пароля. Соответственно, напишите одну функцию, которую и будете вызывать с нужными параметрами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас нет "сильной" дубликации кода, на самом деле у вас дублируются только две строки, но это меньшая проблема нежели повторные проверки или возврат мусора в вашей фукции. Учитывая, что ваши стратегии наследуются от базового класса, предлагаю сделать подобным образом

```cpp
    Strateg *_strateg = nullptr;

    if (_strat == "simple"){
        _strateg = new Simple;
    } else
    if (_strat == "medium"){
        _strated = new Medium;
    } else
    if (_strat == "strong"){
        _strated = new Strong;
    }

    if (_strategy) {
        PasswordGenerator _pwdgen;
        _pwdgen.setStrategy(&_strateg);
        std::string retval =  _pwdgen.useStrategy(_lenght_pass, _alphabet);
        delete _strateg;
        return retval;
    }

    return "";
```

PS и лучше не применяйте имена переменных начиная с подчеркивания: хоть зарезервированными считаются только имена с двумя подчеркиваниями, но разработчики `stl` могут применять и имена с одним подчеркиванием - такое бывает

Comment: спасибо большое,помогло)
А насчет переменных - буду знать

Comment: Это немного паранойя, но если тело `if` бросит исключение, память утечет. Я бы `unique_ptr` использовал.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat совершенно верно, но я думаю это стоит оставить на усмотрение автора

Answer (score 1):

Я бы вынес дублирующийся код в лямбду, примерно так:

```
PasswordGenerator _pwdgen;
auto lambda = [&](auto &&_strateg)
{
    _pwdgen.setStrategy(&_strateg);
    return _pwdgen.useStrategy(_lenght_pass, _alphabet);
};
if (_strat == "simple")
    return lambda(Simple{});
if (_strat == "medium")
    return lambda(Medium{});
```

Comment: спасибо большое)